# Stored Procedure to Import XML into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to import XMLs into SQL Server. If I print the below @command, I can copy and paste into SSMS and the code runs perfectly. However, I get the following error if I try to run this as an sp.

```
exec etl.import_xml 'c:\xml_file.xml'
```

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Must declare the scalar variable "@stream".

```
ALTER PROCEDURE etl.import_xml (
    @file_name      VARCHAR(1000)
) AS 
BEGIN       
    DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @stream VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @command = N'SELECT @stream = CAST(BulkColumn AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @file_name + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;'
    --EXEC sp_executesql @command, N'@file_stream_out VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @stream_out = @stream OUTPUT
    EXECUTE(@command)
    SET @stream = dbo.strip_xmlns(@stream)  

    UPDATE swf.etl.raw_data
    SET xml_string = CONVERT(XML, @stream)
    WHERE xml_file_name = @file_name
END
```

Comment: When you call dynamic SQL you create a new context, and variables which exist in the calling context do not exist in the new dynamic context. Hence `@Stream` only exists in the outer context, but not when you call `execute`. If you were using `sp_executesql`, which is the best practice way to call dynamic SQL, you can pass parameters into and out of the dynamic context.

Comment: Why have you commented out the instance of `[sys.]sp_executesql`? You clearly *knew* that there was a correct way to execute the statement, and then chose to not use it. (Though you do give the parameter the wrong name (`@file_stream_out`) for the dynamic SQL.)

Comment: Experimenting, to see if I was over complicating things.

Comment: Also, that query is ***WIDE*** open to injection attacks. You **need** to ensure that you the value of `@filename` is properly quoted and escaped.

Answer (score 0):

As per Dale K, I need to declare everything within the command string. Obviously there are still issues with SQL injection, however no user will have access to this proc and will only be run on an automation server.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE etl.import_xml (
    @file_name      VARCHAR(1000)
) AS 
BEGIN       
    DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @stream VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @command = N'DECLARE @stream VARCHAR(MAX) SELECT @stream = CAST(BulkColumn AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @file_name + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
                    SET @stream = dbo.strip_xmlns(@stream)  
                    UPDATE swf.etl.raw_data
                    SET xml_string = CONVERT(XML, @stream)
                    WHERE xml_file_name = ''' + @file_name + '''
                    '
    EXECUTE(@command)


END
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with an XML file name as a parameter.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML
   , @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
   , @fileName VARCHAR(256) = 'e:\Temp\Diego.xml';

SET @sql = N'SELECT @xmlOut = XmlDoc FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ' + QUOTENAME(@fileName,NCHAR(39)) + ', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Tab(XmlDoc)';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@xmlOut XML OUTPUT', @xmlOut = @xml OUTPUT;

SELECT @xml;
```